# Trigger errror ER_CANT_UPDATE_USED_TABLE_IN_SF_OR_TRG: Can't update table

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I have used a trigger to update a table when data is inserted in the same table ! But when i insert data in that table i get error

```
ER_CANT_UPDATE_USED_TABLE_IN_SF_OR_TRG: Can't update table
```

What does this mean ?

Trigger COde :

```
create trigger update_owners_leaving_time 
AFTER INSERT ON cc_owners_queries 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
update cc_owners_queries set leaving_time = query_time + INTERVAL leaving_in MINUTE , trigger_updated = 1 where trigger_updated !=1;
    END
```

Error:

> Error: ER_CANT_UPDATE_USED_TABLE_IN_SF_OR_TRG: Can't update table 'cc_owners_queries' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Comment: Maybe because the update, triggers that trigger, which will cause an infinite loop?

Comment: @Niels I didn't get you !

Comment: The trigger will cause an update. which will trigger, which will update, which will trigger,, and so on.

Comment: @vipulsodha Can you share your trigger's code please?

Comment: @Mureinik yes I did that !

Comment: @Niels i have put the exact error now !

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something llike this:

```
create trigger update_owners_leaving_time 
AFTER INSERT ON cc_owners_queries 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF NEW.trigger_updated != 1 THEN
        set NEW.leaving_time = NEW.query_time + INTERVAL NEW.leaving_in MINUTE;
        SET NEW.trigger_updated = 1;
    END IF;
END
```

You don't have to say you need to update the current table. You loop through the rows.. and that row will be the target.

More info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html